# Typed arrays in generic functions

Tags: typescript

In a library I have a helper function that works with arrays of any type. Now I want to extend that to accept also [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), but I cannot find a common base class, nor are typed arrays generic. This is the code I have so far for generic arrays and one typed array:

```js
    public static copyOf(original: Int32Array, newLength: number): Int32Array;
    public static copyOf<T>(original: T[], newLength: number): T[];
    public static copyOf<T>(original: T[] | Int32Array, newLength: number): T[] | Int32Array {
        if (original instanceof Int32Array) {
            if (newLength < original.length) {
                return original.slice(0, newLength);
            }

            if (newLength === original.length) {
                return original.slice();
            }

            const result = new Int32Array(newLength);
            result.set(original);

            return result;

        } else {
            if (newLength < original.length) {
                return original.slice(0, newLength);
            }

            if (newLength === original.length) {
                return original.slice();
            }

            const result = new Array<T>(newLength);
            result.splice(0, 0, ...original);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

This approach would however require to add an own branch for every typed array type, which would defeat the idea of generics. How can this be implemented in a more compact way?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlLzlN) meet your needs?  Please test.  If it works for you then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that looks very promising and works in the playground. That trick with the constructor is great.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll write up an answer when I get the chance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First for the typings, since this is TypeScript. There isn't currently a built in type corresponding to typed arrays; see [microsoft/TypeScript#15402](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15402).  But nothing stops you from defining your own as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the relevant individual types.  Here's one possibility:

```
type TypedArray = Int8Array | Uint8Array | Int16Array | Uint16Array | Int32Array |
  Uint32Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Float32Array | Float64Array;
```

I haven't included [`BigInt64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt64Array) or [`BigUint64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array) in there, because they don't have the same exact behavior as the others (you need `bigint` and not `number`), but you could add those if you need to.

---

Now for the implementation.  One approach is to use the [`constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) of the typed array you pass in to get the right class constructor, and use it to construct a new instance.  TypeScript won't be happy about you doing this, since it doesn't model strongly typed `constructor` properties (see [ms/TS#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) for a lengthy discussion about this)... so we'll need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that it's acceptable.

Possibly like this:

```
class Foo {
  public static copyOf<T extends TypedArray>(original: T, newLength: number): T;
  public static copyOf<T>(original: T[], newLength: number): T[];
  public static copyOf<T>(original: T[] | TypedArray, newLength: number): T[] | TypedArray {
    if (!Array.isArray(original)) {
      if (newLength < original.length) {
        return original.slice(0, newLength);
      }
      if (newLength === original.length) {
        return original.slice();
      }
      const result = new (original.constructor as new (arg: number) => TypedArray)(newLength);
      result.set(original);
      return result;
    } else {
      if (newLength < original.length) {
        return original.slice(0, newLength);
      }
      if (newLength === original.length) {
        return original.slice();
      }
      const result = new Array<T>(newLength);
      original.forEach((v, i) => result[i]=v); // splice doesn't do what you want
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

where instead of checking for `instanceof` to check that the value is a particular typed array, I check with [the `Array.isArray()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check that the value *isn't* a built-in array.

(Also note that I had to change away from [the `splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) which *inserts* things, causing the resulting array to be longer than you intend.)

If you needed to support the `BigInt64Array` and `BigUint64Array` then you'd have to add a type assertion on the `result.set(original);` line to prevent an error.

---

Let's make sure it works:

```
const arr = Foo.copyOf(new Int16Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 10);
// const arr: Int16Array
console.log(arr) // Int16Array: ...

const arr2 = Foo.copyOf(["a", "b", "c"], 4);
// const arr2: string[]
console.log(arr2) // ["a", "b", "c", ]
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEBMCCAnFBDEUC8UCSAdsAByoZYA+UAqgJZGlqZRWHACMAbGc1XUVx6V8RAMwAmISwBQUGvWASpfBcQDCAG3QBbSMibCAYhoD26RZIMsoxs8E4AWIQG5p0gMZaAzl5smTUADeslBgAK4ARhq07lBewOYxUO4mYCAA8gBmADwwUBAAHsAQBAi+cHpCAHwAFCYotADm9OgaAFywADRQBBAA7gAyJY3AABYdBGHaERAoAJQdMK5y4VFJ8YmxKWlZubX1TS3tsADaALrdvYPDYxNTM-OL58uhkdGxG8BJ2xk5MPsNZoEVpPM7WCqIISXfpDAgjcY9e6zBanMFUCH6chBEJyWiZKA1ACEQgAdLQvEI6oCjnM5ti5AyoHiCVdYfCoNkoAcga0SRobqM6cFGYyUBBgGEUAQudTgRoSV53hAagAGaHXOFjOYvRkAXxxDOZNVZApw2Fw3KOfIFQoNovFkullrlCqVNW1dqg+pFyRMBHiUDFXjCGmAOB6-QJzt5KX9wBQYXcwHqUHQviuBPQKEad2myJwVVg8ExmDmxphNp1DKDIeACvFVMOco9PrFEqlgYgwdDVd1+Q0XmgwpFRpNmtGHJlTd5-PHtp9cjbjqnPPlipiyrVEY18JbIu9I-x5Z3YzNFtlM5t9IXS470bXbr3es9sYDNdD4YzQj2x7ZWqrcj3iSmT1AAoug7ijDUNQAG7dLQdLYIW77ACctBnNgMFPtWDodihvYhPq+qvmGWYoOGhj+CSPxZMeIgcNwBg1Cc7DdOI3SiN0DjdAArGcczdOwKoegA9CJvpxqmaAdGwggGB4fpeCY-J8iYjQ1GRdJifRcnkB0JIGW4JFSSg4gUVRNGZMxABE6DWd01kRPZUDWe41kXFADiieJxlkeIHTxA0cLnAp-rKRAqnqX5WniSctnOY5CVud0ZxuEAA)